# How to add json array to a json document in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, jsonpath

I have an array like this :

```
[{"Name": "abcd"}, {"Name": "efgh"}, {"Name": "hijk"}]
```

I have to insert this to json document

My json document is similar to this :

```
 {"widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        }  

    }}
```

How to append array to json document in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `json` library-

```
import json

js="""
{"widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        }  

    }}  

"""
l=[{"Name": "abcd"}, {"Name": "efgh"}, {"Name": "hijk"}]

l_dict=json.loads(json.dumps(l))

js_dict = json.loads(js)
js_dict['widget']['window']['name']=l_dict[0]['Name']


print js_dict
print js_dict['widget']['window']['name']
```

Prints- See printed `JSON` is with `new name`!

```
{u'widget': {u'debug': u'on', u'window': {u'width': 500, u'height': 500, u'name': 'abcd', u'title': u'Sample Konfabulator Widget'}}}
abcd
```